# Regex match float number inside of a string with any char or space in between

Tags: python, regex

My regex

`\d+\.*\d+`

my String

`4a 1 a2 3 21 12a3 123.12`

What I get:

```
['21', '12', '123.12']
```

What I need:

`412321123123.12`

I do work well when there is just 123.12 for example but when I add spaces or new chars in between it separates them. I want it to skip all the spaces and chars and to extract just numbers separated with '.' in the right position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove everything that is not a digit or a point:

```
import re


result = re.sub('[^.\d]', '', '4a 1 a2 3 21 12a3 123.12')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
412321123123.12
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex-free alternative:

```
>>> s = '4a 1 a2 3 21 12a3 123.12'
>>> 
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit() or c == '.')
>>> '412321123123.12'
```

Using a list comprehension with `str.join` is [slightly  faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024) than the generator-comprehension, i.e.:

```
>>> ''.join([c for c in s if c.isdigit() or c == '.'])
>>> '412321123123.12'
```

This assumes that you want to keep multiple `.` or that you don't expect more than one.